# Sapui5/Openui5/Javascript two Popups on one Inputfield: closes one instantly again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sapui5

I have two popups on on single date inputfield. One on the right side of the date field to indicate an validation input error to the user. The other one underneath or above the field to show an calendar picker. The problem is that the calendar picker closes immediately after opening if "autoclose" is "true". The popups are of type sap.ui.ux3.ToolPopup. I also tried sap.m.Popup. The behavior is the same, still same problem. How can I solve this problem? Here is what I did for the calendar picker.

```
//called on init
this._calendarPopup = new sap.ui.ux3.ToolPopup({
        content : [ this._calendar ], //complete calendar control which should be displayed on the popup
        opener : _self,
        autoClose : false,
        openDuration : 1,
        closeDuration : 1,
        closed : function() {
            _self.unselectDates();
        },
    })

this.attachBrowserEvent("click", function() {//if the field is a date Field attach the calendar picker
        if (_self.get_dataType() == "date") {
            _self.onOpenCalendar();
        }
    });
//end called on init

onOpenCalendar : function() {
    var _self = this;
    if (this.get_changeable()) {
        _self._calendarPopup.setOpener(_self.getId());
        _self._calendarPopup.open(sap.ui.core.Popup.Dock.LeftTop, sap.ui.core.Popup.Dock.LeftBottom);
    }
},
```

Currently the calendar closes just on date selection. Which is not a user friendly behavior. The calendar should also close when the user clicks outside the calendar (without setting a date).

Similar attachBrowserEvent function for the error popup.

```
//called on init in other class tha
this.cancelCommentPopup = new sap.ui.ux3.ToolPopup({
        content : [ this.cancelCommentText ],
        autoClose : true,
        openDuration : 1,
        closeDuration : 1,
    }).addStyleClass("CancelCommentPopup");


onOpenCancelCommentPopup : function(openerControl, entity, i, field) {
    this.cancelCommentPopup.setOpener(openerControl.getId());
    this.cancelCommentText.setText(JSON.parse(entity.response.body).error.message.value);
    this.cancelCommentPopup.open(sap.ui.core.Popup.Dock.BeginCenter);
},
```

Comment: why dont you work with the events of  sap.ui.ux3.ToolPopup? (see https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.ux3.ToolPopup.html). There is close(), closed() etc; therefore pass everypopup an ID, which enables you to work on events of the others, lets say input on popup1 should raise an error in popup2? do I get you right? I think self refers to both of the popups which ends in closing both.

Answer (score 0):

Thx @zyrex, thats the way.

```
field._calendarPopup.attachOpen(function(e) {
        _self.cancelCommentPopup.setOpener(field.getId());
        _self.cancelCommentText.setText(JSON.parse(entity.response.body).error.message.value);
        _self.cancelCommentPopup.open(sap.ui.core.Popup.Dock.BeginCenter);
});
```

Attaching on the open Method of the calendar with attachOpen() the opening of the cancelCommentPopup. And the same for close.

```
field._calendarPopup.attachClosed(function(e) {
        _self.cancelCommentPopup.close();
});
```

Works perfect. Problem solved.